# Notepad++ find all regular expression with condition

Tags: php, regex, string, text, notepad++

Title is pretty much self explanatory...

I want to find a particular match but with condition.

I will give an example so it would be more clear:

```
http://www.example.com//test.htm
https://www.example.com/test.htm
https://www.example.com///test.htm
ftp://www.example.com//myFile.jpg
```

I want to find all // but except the the http://

so iow...

if there is a `:` character (http://) before the `//` ignore it...

return only matches that do not have `:` before `//`

Comment: In most regexes it's the negative lookbehind: `(?<!:)//`, no idea if NP++ supports this.

Comment: @georg You should post that as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @georg would work for your case, if you want to make sure you're ignoring those specific conditions; you could use multiple lookbehind assertions:

```
(?<!http:)(?<!https:)(?<!ftp:)//
```

Comment: Thanks man ! I'm still using georg method... It covers all cases :)